# Reusing local variables through Reduce and ToRules

Tags: equation-solving, variable-definitions, variable

**Problem:** I am interested in solving a system of linear equations through Mathematica. In my current test scenario, I am having trouble using the Reduce function followed by the ToRules command. I would like to access the output of the ToRules command later in my Mathematica notebook.

**Test Scenario:** Suppose I am interested in calling the output of Subscript[v, 1] and Subscript[v, 2] in the following Reduce function

```
solveVars = 
 Reduce[ -(((-1 + t^2) Subscript[d, 1] + (-1 + t^2) Subscript[r, 1] + 
         2 t \[Alpha] Subscript[v, 1])/(1 + t^2)) == Subscript[r, 
    2] && (2 t Subscript[d, 1] + 
       2 t Subscript[r, 
         1] - \[Alpha] (A (1 + t^2) + (-1 + t^2) Subscript[v, 
            1]))/((1 + t^2) \[Alpha]) == Subscript[v, 2], {A, 
   t, \[Alpha], Subscript[d, 1], Subscript[r, 1], Subscript[r, 2], 
   Subscript[v, 1], Subscript[v, 2]}]
```

The above Mathematica code will generate an explicit solution for Subscript[v, 1] and Subscript[v, 2] (as I am new to this site, I don't know how to format the output cells from Mathematica notebook nicely on stack exchange.) I can then find the result of Subscript[v, 1] and Subscript[v, 2] through

```
ans = ToRules[solveVars[[2]]];
ans[[1]] (*Subscript[v, 1]*)
ans[[2]] (*Subscript[v, 2]*)
```

which gives me

```
Subscript[v, 1] -> expression_1
Subscript[v, 2] -> expression_2
```

However, I don't know how to access what is in expression_1 and expression_2 later in the notebook. So, writing something similar to

```
MatrixForm[{Subscript[v, 1], Subscript[v, 2], 1}]
```

doesn't generate the values of "expression_1 and expression_2" found through the ToRules command. How could I change this code (or write similar code) in order to substitute the values of Subscript[v, 1] and Subscript[v, 2] into later commands in a Mathematica notebook?

Comment: How about `{savevalueofSubscriptv1forlater,savevalueofSubscriptv2forlater}={Subscript[v,1],Subscript[v,2]}/.ans` and then you can later use `savevalueofSubscriptv1forlater` or `savevalueofSubscriptv2forlate` in future expressions. I would urge caution in using any of the "Form"s, like `MatrixForm` etc unless you know more than enough to use those correctly. Mostly those "Form"s are for display purposes only and will give you confusing and surprising results if you try to use those as parts of calculations.

Comment: `ans[[1]][[2]]` and `ans[[2]][[2]]` gives you the expressions!

Comment: `exprs = Last /@ Last@{ToRules@solveVars}`

Comment: These strategies work. Thank you for the helpful comments.